# ¿Qué significa esta multiplicación?

Tags: javascript

¿Qué significa, en JavaScript, multiplicar por un número antecedido por un punto?

osea:

```
4 * .2
```

Comment: Esta es una pregunta muy básica, es posible que te la cierren pues esa es la opinión mayoritaria en meta ahora mismo. Si te interesa cambiar o afianzar esa posición puedes votar en [Reabriendo:¿Cómo funciona el preprocesador de C++?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2184/reabriendo-c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-preprocesador-de-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.2` es un número, **en coma flotante**.

```
4 * .2
```

Es lo mismo que

```
4 * 0.2
```